# Ubuntu Intel Raid on an AMD Ubuntu System

Tags: mount, raid, intel, amd-ryzen

The title really sums up my question, I am running a Ryzen AMD system with ubuntu 18.04(If I am correct). I have access to two ssd's that were previously function under a raid 0 in a now dead sandy bridge system.
Is there some way that I may mount these drives within this environment. That would permit for me to read and backup the contents of these drives. While avoiding the risks of accidentally making the error of deleting their contents inadvertently through confusion?

[Drive 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOJSp.png)

[Drive 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCPUW.png)

Comment: RAID-0 requires both drives be installed and mounted before you can get any data out. You had these in an Intel CPU system using Intel's software RAID, so to access them, you will need to recreate that hardware environment with another Intel based system, with the same OS.

Comment: They where actually mounted under the hardware raid function which booted before the os itself